# Comment out code using vimscript

Tags: vim

Hi Im trying to write my first vim script. I want to write a function that will comment out PHP code by the block or curly brackets.

Here is what I've come up with, but I can't get it to work:

```
:function Mycom()
    :let b = line(".")
    :echo "this is "b
    // trying to grab the matching bracket, not sure wheather this is ok
    :%
    //keeps missing and going to end og file
    :let e = line(".")
    :echo "here is end" e
    //here is where i want to comment out the block
    :echo b,e s%^%//%
:endfunction
```

Comment: You're not supposed to add `:` before keywords like that. Just do `function MyCom()`, `let b = line(".")` etc.

Comment: @timss But it's perfectly legal and not the source of any problems that Brett is having, as opposed to all of the obvious errors in the echo statement etc. Brett, read your error messages.

Comment: @FizzyTea May be so, but it's meaningless, ugly and adds confusion.

Comment: @timss Ugly, yes. Adds confusion, no (though it is the result of confusion). E.g. the error with `:%` is quite obvious. `://` would be more obvious that it's doing a regexp search.

Comment: If you want a more general solution to your commenting needs I suggest something like https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary which will allow you do do `gciB` which will comment/uncomment an inner block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You shouldn’t put a leading `:` on each line — **unless** you’re writing the function in the Vim command line, Vim will add the `:` automatically for you. (It‘d be better to write your script in a file, though; that way it’s easier to modify and test.)
- Comments in Vimscript start with `"` (a double quote), not `//`.
- If you want to execute a normal mode command, like `%` or `dd`, you can use `normal! %` or `normal! dd`.
- `echo b,e s%...` won’t work. If you want to `echo` the text, try `echo b.','.e.' s%^%//%'`.

Also, consider using `echom` instead of `echo`. Because `echom` saves the message in the message history, you can re-read it later using `:mess`.

**P.S.** If your cursor is on an open `{` (I saw you’re trying to use `%` in your script), you can comment the block using

`ctrl-v%I//<esc>`

Comment: ok great but it wont execute b.','.e.' s%^%//%' its just echoing

Comment: that what you want to do, you had `echo` on that line, if you want to execute the cmd, remove your `:echo` from that line

Comment: so i use :let  b.','.e.' s%^%//%

Comment: try `exec b.','.e.' s%^%//%'`

Comment: awsome man thank you works perfect.. So do i map a key to that function now is that how it works?